# Writing Specs for ActiveRecord association extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord, rspec

E.g., given a model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos do
    def find_or_create_or_bar!(foo_name, foo_params)
      # ... stuff
      find_by_name(foo_name) || create!(foo_params) || bar!
    end
  end
end
```

can anyone recommend a good way to write specs for the behavior?

```
describe User do
  describe "#foos" do
    describe "#find_or_create_or_bar!" do
      # ???
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a good approach to thinking about these kinds of specs? What should I be specifying? Since these are associations, is it even possible to specify the `User` class in isolation here?

Comment: Not sure if this is just an example of what you're trying to do, but your code is already built into ActiveRecord: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html Read dynamic attribute-based finders

Comment: @Beerlington -- yeah sorry, my example was not too creative. I meant to emphasize the `# ... stuff` part, which is not part of `ActiveRecord`'s dynamic `find_or_create` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about the User spec knowing too much about the Foo model, you can try moving this logic to a class method on Foo:

Something like this should work:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.find_or_create_or_bar!(name, params)
    # ... stuff
    find_by_name(name) || create!(params) || bar!
  end

end
```

Then you can test this outside of the User model/spec. You may also want to do an integration test that ensures User and Foo interact the way you want. You can use Rspec for this, but I find Cucumber to be a better fit when there's more logic involved.

Comment: I use Cucumber a lot, but I tend to use it for higher level stuff -- i.e. at the browser level. Do you ever use Cucumber for integration testing directly on your models?

Comment: Also, does `Foo.find_or_create_or_bar!(name, params)` work on `User`'s association? `some_user.foos.find_or_create_or_bar!(...)`

Comment: I assumed you were using Rails 3, this may not work with Rails 2 :/

Comment: I typically don't use Cucumber for lower level model testing, as that's what Test::Unit or Rspec are designed for. What I meant was that you will want a higher level test that uses this class method. This is really just a built in behavior of Rails, so unit testing the association method call is slightly redundant.

Comment: Ahh yeah that's what I try to do in most cases. I guess what prompted me to ask this question is that I just wrote one method in which the `# ... stuff` part is pretty complex. I wanted to spec that behavior out pretty closely to ensure proper behavior.